# Create auto download backup from web with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

please help me,
what should i do to get auto click in wrapper menu website on chrome?
I intend to create an automated program that runs on the website. but can't auto click on menu wrapper in chrome.
I've tried by class, by text, by xpath still can't work

```
    from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
        driver.get("http://192.168.1.1/htdocs/login/login.lsp")
       usr = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
    usr.send_keys('admin')
    elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
    elem.send_keys('t3s3r4hl4H')
    btn = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_button")
    btn.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    btn = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Maintenance")
    btn.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    btn = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Backup and Update Manager")
    btn.click()
    btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='b_form1_bt_http_upload']").click()
    btn.click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUm28.png)

error:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Music> python web2.py
C:\Users\User\Music\web2.py:5: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57319/devtools/browser/d4ffcaec-297e-4b91-886e-24788f62a805
[17892:17472:0901/155323.481:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:53:23.481] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Music\web2.py", line 19, in <module>
    btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='b_form1_bt_http_upload']").click()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='b_form1_bt_http_upload']"}
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.54)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x0089DF13+2219795]
        Ordinal0 [0x00832841+1779777]
        Ordinal0 [0x0074423D+803389]
        Ordinal0 [0x00773025+995365]
        Ordinal0 [0x007731EB+995819]
        Ordinal0 [0x007A0F52+1183570]
        Ordinal0 [0x0078E844+1108036]
        Ordinal0 [0x0079F192+1175954]
        Ordinal0 [0x0078E616+1107478]
        Ordinal0 [0x00767F89+950153]
        Ordinal0 [0x00768F56+954198]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B92CB2+3040210]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B82BB4+2974420]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00936A0A+565546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00935680+560544]
        Ordinal0 [0x00839A5C+1808988]
        Ordinal0 [0x0083E3A8+1827752]
        Ordinal0 [0x0083E495+1827989]
        Ordinal0 [0x008480A4+1867940]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7594FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7A6E+238]

PS C:\Users\User\Music> [17892:16264:0901/155419.539:ERROR:util.cc(129)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater
[13288:2568:0901/155519.534:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

Comment: Hello, What exactly is the problem? Is the program not doing anything? Are you getting an error? please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: yes sir, the program not doing anything and not click otomatically and open wrap menu on chrome

Comment: You probably need to click on some other element to open the list and then to click on the list item.

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: I've updated my question, but I have a new problem onclick wiget